# InvalidCastException in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, struct, .net

(Using VS 2010 Beta 2 - .Net 4.0 B2 Rel)

I have a class, MyTable, derived from BindingList where S is a struct.  S is made up of several other structs, for example:

```
public class MyTable<S>:BindingList<S> where S: struct
{
    ...
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public MyReal r1;
    public MyReal r2;

    public MyReal R1 {get{...} set{...}}
    public MyReal R2 {get{...} set{...}}

    ...
}

public struct MyReal
{
    private Double d;

    private void InitFromString(string) {this.d = ...;}

    public MyReal(Double d) { this.d = d;}
    public MyReal(string val) { this.d = default(Double);  InitFromString(val);}

    public override string ToString() { return this.real.ToString();}
    public static explicit operator MyReal(string s) { return new MyReal(s);}
    public static implicit operator String(MyReal r) { return r.ToString();}
    ...
}
```

OK, I use the MyTable as a binding source for a DataGridView.  I can load the data grid easily using InitFromString on individual fields in MyStruct.

The problem comes when I try to edit a value in a cell of the DataGridView.   Going to the first row, first column, I change the value of the existing number. It gives an exception blizzard, the first line of which says:

System.FormatException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'MyReal'

I've looked at the casting discussions and reference books but don't see any obvious problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a System.FormatException, not an InvalidCastException?  Check the stack trace, what's throwing the exception?

Comment: Maybe its because your operator casting from string to real is explicit and not implicit?

Comment: It's both exceptions.  The Default Error Dialog reports'
    System.FormatException:Invalid cast from 'System.String' 
    to 'MyReal' --> System.InvalidCastException: 
    Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'MyReal'

Comment: I think I need to handle parsing and formatting event explicity instead of stubbing in to use the default handler.

Comment: @MaxYaffe Just reviewing some old answers I posted, and I'm wondering if we were of any help on this one?

Comment: A very old issue. Not found any solution yet, that would be useful to me I want to have actual units instead of double.

Answer (score 3):

I tried your method of handling CellParsing, and it worked. Although I did it a little differently, handling any types:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Value = Activator.CreateInstance(e.DesiredType, new object[] { e.Value });
        e.ParsingApplied = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The DataGridView uses a [TypeConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter?view=netframework-4.8).

You must define a TypeConverter object for your structure and decorate it with the TypeConverterAttribute, so that the DataGridView uses it as soon as it encounters a property that is typed with your structure.

The example I give here of such a TypeConverter is a bit rudimentary, but the Degree structure I use is similar to yours, it will give you a good idea of what to do.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(DegreeConverter))]
public struct Degree {
    double Value;
    public Degree(double v) { Value = v; }
    public static implicit operator double(Degree v) => v.Value;
    public static implicit operator Degree(double v) => new Degree(v);
    public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();
}

class DegreeConverter : TypeConverter {
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType) {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) ? true : base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType) {
        return destinationType == typeof(string) ? true : base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        return new Degree(Convert.ToDouble(value));
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType) {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I (almost) fixed this problem by handling the CellParsing event, e.g.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    ... // (checking goes here)
    e.Value = new MyReal(e.Value.ToString());
    e.ParsingApplied = true;
}
```

e.Value is being set correctly but the DataGridView still shows the old value.  How does the new value get placed in the BindingList?

Do I need an explicit method call to force the new value into the BindingList and, if so, where?

Answer (score 0):

My gridcells are filled with objects of type `GridValueGroup` and they have an `ObjValue` property displayed by the `ToString` override. When modifying the string in the grid cell, the `CellParsing` event is handled by:

1. filling the cell-value and
2. modifying the `e.Value` (which is of type `string` initially while the `DesiredType` is `GridValueGroup`) to become the desired type.

This way I avoid creating a new object because the cell already has that object.

Also it keeps the entered value in the data source. Not certain yet if it blocks other events (`CellValueChanged` has to be handled sometimes after the parsing of the value).

```
     private void grid_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e) {
        string val = e.Value.ToString();

        DataGridViewCell cell = this.dgvGroup1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

        if (e.DesiredType == typeof(GridValueGroup))
        {
            ((GridValueGroup)cell.Value).ObjValue = val;
            e.Value = ((GridValueGroup)cell.Value);
        }
        e.ParsingApplied = true;

    }
```